# How to get the coefficient list

Tags: polynomials

```
polynomial=-x^4+2 b x^3+(b^2-c^2+2 c) x^2+(2 b c-2 c d) x+c^2-d^2
```

This is good

```
CoefficientList[polynomial, x]
```

But how to get coefficient list from the `PolynomialForm`?

I've tried this, but it does not give the coefficient list.

```
CoefficientList[PolynomialForm@polynomial,x]
```

Comment: Closely related in the canonical Q&A is the last part of [this answer by Verbeia](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4330). Perhaps that could be expanded to for example contain a "if you really have to" approach like the one by Anon below.

Comment: Do you require something like `CoefficientList[#[[1]], x] &@PolynomialForm@polynomial`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot perform operations on a display type. Trying to operate on `PolynomialForm` is like trying to operate on `TableForm`. You're supposed to first do all the processing on your expression and then choose how you want to display it. If you absolutely have to do this, you have to first get the data inside `PolynomialForm` again and work on that, which can be done like this:

```
CoefficientList[PolynomialForm[polynomial] /. PolynomialForm[x_] :> x,x]
```